# In Linux, how to execute Java jar file with external jar files?

Tags: java, linux, jar, execution

In Linux, how to execute Java jar file with external jar files?

Answer (score 11):

Either use the `-cp` flag:

```
java -cp /path/to/somefolder/*.jar:/path/to/otherfolder/*.jar com.YourMainClass
```

Or add a `Class-Path:` header to your jar's manifest (see Jigar's answer)

---

**Note** to others who answered with `java -jar <etc>`: The `-jar` flag deactivates the standard `-cp` flag and `CLASSPATH` environment variable, because it retrieves the classpath from the JAR  manifest. Any answer that combines `-jar` and either `-cp` or `$CLASSPATH` will not work.

This information is well-hidden, but I finally found a reference:

> **-jar**
>   Execute a program encapsulated in a JAR file. The first argument is the
>   name of a JAR file instead of a
>   startup class name. In order for this
>   option to work, the manifest of the
>   JAR file must contain a line of the
>   form Main-Class: classname. Here,
>   classname identifies the class having
>   the *`public static void main(String[]
>   args)`* method that serves as your
>   application's starting point. See the
>   Jar tool reference page and the Jar
>   trail of the Java Tutorial for
>   information about working with Jar
>   files and Jar-file manifests. **When you
>   use this option, the JAR file is the
>   source of all user classes, and other
>   user class path settings are ignored.**

**Source:** [java - the Java application launcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

Answer (score 7):

```
java -jar /path/to/externalJarFile.jar
```

**Update**

You can add the required library in manifest with `Class-Path:` header

For example :

```
Class-Path: MyUtils.jar
```

**See**

- [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Comment: for example i want to execute sample.jar file.but its required additional jar files(say add.jar) located with differnt path.Now how to execute sample.jar

Comment: This is the first correct answer here that features the -jar flag (+1)