# Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver while running JAR through Command line

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector

I have a java program in that I am using **mysql** database connectivity code.
I have added **mysql-connector-java-3.0.10-stable-bin.jar** and **mysql-connector-java-5.0.4-bin.jar** files in my resource folder in eclipse.
When I run the program in Eclipse it runs fine.
Then I have created a **.jar** file of my project included all jar files in that jar file.
But when I run my **jar** file with **java -jar myJar.jar** command on DOS prompt it gives the error - **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**

I tried with setting CLASSPATH of mysql-connector*.jar but still getting the same error.
Please help me to resolve this problem?

Thanks in Advance ....

Comment: What does this command do? ```java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.0.4-bin.jar -jar myJar.jar```

Comment: @opyate: nothing useful: If you use `-jar` then all other classpath sources (`CLASSPATH` variable and `-cp` switch) will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks opyate for reply, I tried with this command but getting same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the problem you can create "**Runnable Jar file**" instead of "**Simple Jar file**" in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

[You need to edit `Manifest.txt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) file to set the classpath for jar

**Also See**

- [In Linux, how to execute Java jar file with external jar files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879925/in-linux-how-to-execute-java-jar-file-with-external-jar-files)

Comment: Thanks Jigar Joshi for reply, I tried with setting Class-path in Manifest.txt, but still I am getting the error

Comment: Please describe, what have you set and what is the error message