# Autowiring classes from external jar with Spring

Tags: spring, maven, classpath, classloader

I'm trying to build a standalone application (not running inside an application server) with Spring and I'm facing the following problem :

My standalone application (spring enabled) is depending on another project (bundled as a jar) which contains a lot of services in `com.application.service` (Annotated with `@Service`).

There is no spring related configuration in the external project and the standalone application context is very simple, it only contains :

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.application" />`

Here is an example of Class that depends on a service which can't be acquired :

```
@Service
public class StandaloneService {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;

    // ...
}
```

`StandaloneService` is contained in the standalone application while `SomeService` is in the external jar.

The error :

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.application.SomeService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Here is how I'm creating the `ApplicationContext` and trying to acquire my service :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { "applicationContext.xml" });
    BeanFactory factory = (BeanFactory) context;

    StandaloneService standalone = factory.getBean(StandaloneService.class);
}
```

How I'm building the standalone application :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <index>true</index>
            <manifest>
                <classpathPrefix>./lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>com.application.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

How I'm running it (which leads to the failure) :

`java -jar target/standalone.jar`

What is strange is that if I run it this way it works :

`mvn "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath com.application.Main" -Dexec.executable=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/bin/java -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec`

Could anyone help me figure out why Spring can't see my external services in the first case ?

**EDIT**

This is from the pom.xml of the external jar :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: How do you create the external jar file under target/lib? If you are using eclipse to create the external jar, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242656/spring-annotation-based-controllers-not-working-if-it-is-inside-jar-file) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936295/auto-wiring-annotations-in-classes-from-dependent-jars) may help you.

Comment: I edited my question with the relevant part of the pom.xml used to create the external jar. I added the `<configuration>` part but this is not changing anything to my problem. I'm not using eclipse but netbeans, but I want this to be working out of any IDE's scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three months later, I now have the response thanks to this :
[Annotation scan not scanning external jars in classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505992/annotation-scan-not-scanning-external-jars-in-classpath)

As stated in the accepted answer, when using the **-jar** option the **-cp** option is ignored.

Running my application this way made it working as expected !

```
java -cp target/lib/external.jar:target/standalone.jar package.Main
```

Comment: This is the magic of spring. Keep breaking your head until it bleeds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the location of the external jar file as part of the java command. It would be something like this

java -cp  -jar target/standalone.jar

Comment: I tried this : `java -cp target/lib/external.jar -jar target/standalone.jar` but I'm still getting the same error