# Spring: Error wiring DataSource java security configuration

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, jdbc

I'm not able to ruin my webapp (Spring MVC based) in tomcat. I'm getting this error when trying to configure security over JDBC:

```
08-Apr-2016 13:32:22.502 INFO [localhost-startStop-16] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [com.mycompany.web.configuration.JustINFactWebAppInitializer@68223868, com.mycompany.web.configuration.SecurityWebInitializer@255b7004]
08-Apr-2016 13:32:22.735 INFO [localhost-startStop-16] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
08-Apr-2016 13:32:23.490 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-16] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Excepción enviando evento inicializado de contexto a instancia de escuchador de clase org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource com.mycompany.web.configuration.SecurityConfig.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource com.justinfact.web.configuration.SecurityConfig.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 28 more

08-Apr-2016 13:32:23.508 INFO [localhost-startStop-16] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

I think my java configuration it's ok, but something is wrong. I'm unable to locate the mistake. This is the configuration files:

```
    package com.mycompany.web.configuration;

    import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;
```

WebApplicationInitializer:

```
public class MycompanyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }
}
```

WebConfig:

```
package com.mycompany.web.configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.EnableWebMvcSecurity;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver;
/**
 * Clase que realiza la configuración Spring de la aplicación.
 * 
 * @author Hadeto Uruguay S.L.
 *
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.mycompany.web")
//@Import({SecurityConfig.class})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * Registra la base de datos de backend.
     * 
     * @return DriverManagerDataSource
     */
    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbdb");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("username");
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("password");
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }

    /**
     * Configura Apache Tiles como gestor de vistas.
     * 
     * @return TilesConfigurer
     */
    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tiles = new TilesConfigurer();
        tiles.setDefinitions(new String[] {"/WEB-INF/layout/tiles.xml"});
        tiles.setCheckRefresh(true);
        return tiles;
    }

    /**
     * Registra Apache Tiles como gestor de vistas.
     * 
     * @return TilesConfigurer
     */
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        return new TilesViewResolver();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

SecurityConfig

```
package com.mycompany.web.configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

/**
 * Gestiona la seguridad de la aplicación a nivel Spring
 * 
 * @author Hadeto Uruguay S.L.
 *
 */
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    /**
     * Configura el acceso a la aplicación para los usuarios.
     */
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        String queryUsers = "SELECT bla bla bla bla";
        String queryAuth = "SELECT bla bla bla";
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).
            usersByUsernameQuery(queryUsers).
            authoritiesByUsernameQuery(queryAuth);
    }

    /**
     * Configuración de la seguridad HTTP.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().
            and().
            formLogin().loginPage("/").permitAll().failureUrl("/").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").
            and().
            httpBasic().
            and().
            csrf();
    }

}
```

Root Config

```
package com.mycompany.web.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.justinfact.web"}, 
               excludeFilters={@Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=EnableWebMvc.class)})
public class RootConfig {
}
```

Comment: why `configure()` method is configured with `@Autowired` Property.?

 `@Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception`

Comment: Post the full stack trace and add your `RootConfig`.

Comment: Your security configuration is loaded (at least should) be loaded by the root context the `ContextLoaderListener` this can only acces beans in that context not from its child contexts, ie. context from the `DispatcherServlet`. Your `WebConfig` containing the `DataSource` is loaded by the latter, hence no `DataSource` from the point of the security config. Move the definition to the `RootConfig` as it should be in the first place.

Comment: M. Denium where do you say to change the order of RootConfig definition?

Answer (score 0):

Please add `@Configuration` and `@Service` annotation in your `SecurityConfig` Class.

`@Configuration` enables a Class to Inject a Bean and `@Service` annotation makes Class `SecurityConfig` to `AutoWired`.

> You May try this ... My knowledge is limited and I have suggest you as per the Same Problem scenario that i faced ..

```
@Configuration
@Service
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
```

Thanks.

Comment: No need of `@Service`

Comment: please try this `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mycompany.web","javax.sql.DataSource"})`

Comment: have your referred this >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705664/autowiring-classes-from-external-jar-with-spring

Answer (score 0):

Solved by configuring the AppInitilizer:

```
package com.mycompany.web.configuration;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MyCompanytWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        //return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I also tried to use your solution to add the `WebConfig.class` to my `RootConfigClasses`-Array but now there is no servlet when navigating to my app ``http://localhost:8080`. How did you solve your problem described above?

Comment: Have you implemented WebConfig.java class in configuration folder?