# Spring boot Configuration FileNotFoundException when extending configuration from another spring boot app

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, jar

I have 2 spring boot apps, and I want one of them to extend the configuration properties of the other.  Everything works fine in Eclipse when I run the project as a maven spring boot app, however, when I run the jar or mvn spring-boot: run, I'm getting:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
Failed to parse configuration class [com.xyz.integration.app.my.Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
class path resource [com/xyz/integration/app/pdfthing/ConfigurationManager.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I've searched all over and tried many variations, including:

- @ComponentScan (using both com.xyz.. and classpath)
- @Import
- Class-Path in Manifest to the external jar file ([In Linux, how to execute Java jar file with external jar files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879925/in-linux-how-to-execute-java-jar-file-with-external-jar-files))

Here's part of the configuration class:

```
@Component
@ComponentScan("classpath:com/xyz/integration/app/pdfthing")
public class MyConfigurationManager extends ConfigurationManager{
```

I'm guessing running as a jar doesn't load the external jar in the configuration.  Any thoughts/hints?  Thanks!

Comment: First `@ComponentScan` should be on a `@Configuration` class. Second including a spring boot app in a spring boot app will not work. As a spring boot jar isn't a regular jar (it has a specific structure).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  Would you help me understand why it works in Eclipse, when I choose Run > Spring Boot App?

Comment: I suspect both projects are in the same workspace and in my experience in eclipse everything that is in the workspace is also on the class path.